# list index in Java

Tags: java, list

How can I display the first character of each string in a Java `String` list?

Comment: Is it a list of strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("abcd");
...

for(String word : list) {
    System.out.println(word.charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you turn to something like google [guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to transform your list into a list of chars with the first letter only.

like in

```
    Lists.transform(listOfStrings, new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String input) {
            // check if string is long enough
            return input.substring(0,1);
        }
    });
```

See here for discussion
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

`list` is your `List<String>`

```
for(String str : list)
    System.out.print(str.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Now how different is that from my answer?

Comment: If you want to say i copied it so you wrong, i wrote it clearly from my own head. and i guess it's not...

Comment: No, I didn't mean to say that. All I wanted to say is that it's a duplicate answer :)